# Getting double values from a string

Tags: c

I have a `C` Program that generate or fill vector of char with a string like :

```
.........................
char value[160]
double*  d = NULL;
char * pEnd = NULL;

......................................
```

After filling value with for rx: 551.54 455.61  98

I would to get this double  value , 
here what I've tried :

```
printf(" the string value is %s \n",value); // works fine  
for (i = 0; i<3 ;i++) {
    if( i ==0)
        d[i] = strtod(value,&pEnd);
    else
       d[i] =strtod(pEnd,&pEnd);
    printf(" the value of d is %lf\n",d[i]);
}
```

the program crashes with a `Segmentation fault` error. Any idea how I may solve this? 
thanks in  advance

Comment: char * pEnd = = NULL;  ?
Also, use malloc() or calloc() for pointers.

Comment: Please post real code. Neither `char * pEnd = = NULL;` nor `for ( i = o: i<3 ;i++)` will compile.

Comment: @interjay that the real code and the compilation isn't a program i don'T get any error

Comment: why the down vote ?  I made a mistake by adding =

Comment: So it wasn't the real code... Why insist that it was then? Copy&paste code that you have actually tested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to allocate space for `d`.

Try

```
double d[3] = {0}; // double *d = NULL;
```

If you want to keep using `d` as a pointer, allocate space before assigning

```
double *d = NULL;
d = malloc(3 * sizeof *d);
if (d != NULL) {
    // ... your code using d
    free(d);
} else {
    fprintf(stderr, "Unable to allocate memory for `d`.\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer one question more is possible to get this done with an unknow number of double values ?

Comment: Using the 2nd method (with a pointer, not an array) you can grow the allocated memory as needed by using `realloc()`; but if you just need to print them (or use them one at a time) you can solve your problem with a plain variable.

Answer (score 0):

Neither `d` nor `pEnd` appears to have been allocated.  Also, you've initialized `i` to `o`, which if it isn't a typo (for `0`?), is an undeclared variable (which would prevent your code form compiling).

Comment: `pEnd` does not need to be allocated. It will eventually point somewhere inside the input string.

Answer (score 0):

Note this-

```
char * pEnd = = NULL; // you should not use '==' here
```

First fix this to-

```
char * pEnd = NULL;
```

Then try to allocate memory for `d` and `pEnd` and try it.